# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button whose title i am selecting from the response obtained from server

The response obtained are as follows:

```
[  
 {"Id":"2","Name":"Alex"},  
 {"Id":"5","Name":"AMark"},  
 {"Id":"1","Name":"Karta"},  
 {"Id":"7","Name":"Juan"},  
 {"Id":"6","Name":"Honky"},  
 {"Id":"3","Name":"Nirauk"},  
 {"Id":"4","Name":"Chinua"}  
]
```

And the code to set title of button I am following is below:

```
_ButtonArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.b1,self.b2,self.b3,self.b4,self.b5,self.b6, nil];

-(void)getList:(NSData *)response
{
    NSArray* Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", Array);
    for (UIButton *button  in _ButtonArray) {
        NSLog(@"the tag of button is %ld",(long)button.tag);
        for (NSDictionary* dict in Array)
        {
            if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue] == button.tag)
            {
                [button setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSLog(@"the Id is %@",[dict objectForKey:@"Id"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it crashes and give this exception:

> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b24a7f0"

I can't understand where am I going wrong. Please suggest the error.

The result of NSLog:

```
(
        {
        Id = 2;
        Name = Alex;
    },
        {
        Id = 5;
        Name = AMark;
    },
        {
        Id = 1;
        Name = Karta;
    },
        {
        Id = 7;
        Name = Juan;
    },
        {
        Id = 6;
        Name = Honky;
    },
        {
        Id = 3;
        Name = "Nirauk";
    },
        {
        Id = 4;
        Name = "Chinua";
    }
)
```

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash? Have you used the debugger and stepped through this code? Have you verified the value of each variable at each line?

Comment: Yes,when it goes if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue] == button.tag)
            {
                [button setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSLog(@"the Id is %@",[dict objectForKey:@"Id"]);
            }

Comment: Once again, which line exactly causes the crash? Point out the one line that crashes.

Comment: Check if dict is a valid NSDictionary `if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])`

Comment: What does the first `NSLog()` line print? That will be a clue to you -- you are calling `objectForKey:` on what you think is an `NSDictionary`, but is actually a string.

Comment: the Nslog prints the dictionary

Comment: @Maddy When the debugger goes on line if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue] == button.tag){,it crashes

Comment: can you print this dict

Comment: @Lovely I mean, please show us the exact output from the `NSLog()` statement -- that way we can help you learn to decipher it.

Comment: Which makes sense based on the exception. `Array` does not contain `NSDictionary` objects. It contains `NSString` objects. BTW - my username is not `Maddy`, it's `rmaddy`.

Comment: @Itai Ferber...question edited ,please check

Comment: @Lovely Is this snippet copied and pasted directly from the debugger, or somewhere else? It doesn't seem to be correctly formatted; any additional quotation marks, parentheses, etc. make a difference here. If you add `NSLog(response);`, what does that print? (Precisely, copied and pasted as-is.)

Comment: This is directly copied from debugger

Comment: @Lovely And the result of `NSLog(response)`? (Please paste it formatted as code; it will be easier to read.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm your response format once again. is it having array of dict which you mentioned above or it may have Dict=>Array=>Dict e.g.
 
`{
    [
      {...}
    ]
 }`

**Edit :**

I have executed your code: 
function working fine, I think problem is in way of converting response string to NSData

`NSString *responseString = @"[{"Id":"5","Name":"AMark"}, {"Id":"1","Name":"Karta"}]";` //your response string

`NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

`[self getList:data];` //your function call

this code not crashed.

Comment: The response is same as I mentioned above in question.

Comment: @Lovely can you take value of `NSNumber *num = [dict objectForKey:@"Id"];` and check is it crashes on this line?

Comment: @Lovely Sorry for above code.. it is string try this `NSString *numString = [dict objectForKey:@"Id"];

Comment: 1  NSString *responseString = @"[{\"Id\":\"5\",\"Name\":\"AMark\"}, {\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Karta\"}]"; <br>
    NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; <br>
    [self getList:data];` <br>

Comment: I fixed it...actually there was an error in response function  call.The view used to load before the rsponse comes.